# Set up user access per git repo on Apache on Windows

Tags: apache, git

I'm setting up git repos to be served by Apache on windows. Httpd.conf is pretty straight forward - it forwards requests to git-http-backend and tells Apache to allow access for authenticated users only. It works fine. However what is needed is the ability to specify different AuthUserFile for each repo - for RepoOne.git user usersOneGroup, for RepoTwo.git usersTwoGroup.

I tried specifying different folders within Directory (DirectoryMatch etc) directives but couldn't get it working. Is there a way to set it up? If so how?

The relevant httpd.conf section (borrowed from [this post](http://www.jeremyskinner.co.uk/2010/07/31/hosting-a-git-server-under-apache-on-windows/) mainly):

```
<Directory />
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "git repos"
    AuthUserFile "c:\CommittersPasswords"
    Require valid-user
</Directory>

SetEnv GIT_PROJECT_ROOT C:/Repositories
SetEnv GIT_HTTP_EXPORT_ALL
ScriptAliasMatch \
        "(?x)^/(.*/(HEAD | \
                        info/refs | \
                        objects/(info/[^/]+ | \
                                 [0-9a-f]{2}/[0-9a-f]{38} | \
                                 pack/pack-[0-9a-f]{40}\.(pack|idx)) | \
                        git-(upload|receive)-pack))$" \
                        "C:/Program Files (x86)/git/libexec/git-core/git-http-backend.exe/$1"
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you can live without Apache (or if you are willing to use Apache as a reverse proxy) you might see if [Gitblit](http://gitblit.com) would work for you.  Gitblit was written to be an integrated pure Java Git solution for small workgroups.